# Defining 'newcommand' without brackets

Tags: macros, brackets

I know that in LaTeX `newcommand` is defined as:

```
\newcommand{name}[num] {definition }
```

But I want to define a new command whose argument is not defined between brackets, and it is defined with between \begin and \end commands. For example, something like this:

```
\teststart bla-bla-bla \testend
```

Maybe I should define two `newcommand`s, one for `\teststart` and one for `\testend`.

I should mention that I have seen such commands in the `changebar` package,
`\cbstart` and `\cbend`.

Comment: Could be done with \def, but it looks like you want to define an environment, not a command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A higher level possibility is with `xparse`:

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\teststart}{+u{\testend}}{%
  do something with #1%
}
```

The `+` allows the argument to contain blank lines.

Comment: \def worked for my case but I prefer \NewDocumentCommand and xparse package. This is exactly what I want, specially xparse package lets me define more than one optional argument.

Answer (score 8):

This is possible using TeX's `\def`, where you require a specific *argument text*. The argument text includes both the specific sequence to be replaced, as well as the arguments in the form `#X` (where `X` is a number from `1` through `9`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\teststart#1\testend{left-#1-right} 
\begin{document}

\teststart this is something \testend

\end{document}
```

If you want to allow for paragraph breaks between `\teststart` and `\testend`, then you need to make the definition using `\long`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\long\def\teststart#1\testend{left-#1-right} 
\begin{document}

\teststart this is

something \testend

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can define an environment this way:

```
\newenvironment{test}{<commands to execute at beginning}{<commands for end}
```

You use the environment like this:

```
\begin{test} bla-bla-bla \end{test}
```

If you want to apply a command to the contents of the environment as a whole, you can do this with the `environ` package. The macro `\BODY` stands for the whole body of the environment, so you can apply a command to it.

```
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{test}{<before>\dosomethingtobody{\BODY}<after>}
```

Comment: The \BODY macro is very helpful. Do you know if environ package accepts more than two optional arguments?

Comment: The documentation demonstrates environments that take arguments, both required and optional. But the only way to have more than one optional argument is to use `xparse`, I think. Perhaps this should be a new question?

Answer (score 2):

And for contrast, a rather more low-level approach is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\teststart{%
  \begingroup           % start a group
  \bfseries             % make the content bold, for demo purposes
  \let\testend\endgroup % within this 'environment' (only),
                        % \testend acts to close the group
}
\begin{document}
Here is some text, \teststart which 
has test content\testend within it.

And that content \teststart can go over multiple paragraphs.

For example.\testend
\end{document}
```

This is broadly similar to the way that the `\begin{env}...\end{env}` mechanism works.

The commands `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` create and terminate a group without using `{...}` (which could not, of course, appear unbalanced within a definition).

Comment: Nice, but it does not allow manipulating the argument, because there's none.

Comment: @egreg True, but `\newcommand\teststart[1]{\begingroup \bfseries Test #1: \let\testend\endgroup}` was going to be an exercise for the reader...  Was being able to manipulate the text between `\teststart ...\testend` a requirement?  Hmm: maybe so.  In that case, @Werner's or your solutions would indeed be necessary.